# create a linked list of items containing pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list, dangling-pointer

I have a little problem with my code.
In fact, I can not understand why when inserting in the list in mind, the last element to insert is in the whole list which is impossible according to my algorithm.
So I created 04 classes: STUDENTS, NOTES, CLASSES, MATTERS.
And I created two structures in my file data.h matters_notes and node :

```
class STUDENTS ;
class CLASSES ;

struct node
{
    STUDENTS *students__ ;
    CLASSES *classes__ ;
    node *next ;

};

node insert_();
```

In my data.c file, I create the insert_ () function:

```
node insert_()
{
   node *t = new node() ;
   t = NULL ;
   int i = 0 ;

   STUDENTS s[5] ;
   CLASSES c[5] ;

   for (i ; i != 5 ; i++)
   {
     node *i = new node() ;
     i->students__ = &s[i] ;
     i->classes__ = &c[i] ;
     i->next = t ;
     t = i ;
   }

   return *t ;
}
```

In the main.c file I call the function insert_ :

```
int main()
{
  node x = insert_() ;
  //Assuming the class has a property called name 
  cout<<x.next->students_->name ;
  return 0 ;

}
```

you will realize that the items are not in the list as expected.
In fact, the top of the list is everywhere in the list.
What advised me because I have not found any solutions to this problem

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are trying to implement list by yourself? It's not a smart thing to do (other than academic purposes) nor so easy.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your arrays, eg `STUDENTS s[5] ;` are declared on the stack. When you leave the `insert_` method, they become invalid and dangerous to use.

You need to use `new` to allocate them, but your approach of creating 5 STUDENTS records in an array doesn't really make much sense to me.

The issue comes down to ownership. You could say `STUDENTS* s =  new STUDENTS[5]`, and the same for `c`

But then, you have to think "*who will delete this memory I have allocated?*"

So the better approach is that each node of the link-list should allocate just its own STUDENT and CLASS object when it is created, and should delete it when it self is destroyed.

You will be glad to know, c++11 has a tool to help you do exactly that `std::unique_ptr<STUDENT>` is a pointer to a student which is automatically deleted when the pointer is destroyed. c++14 has an even better tool `std::make_unique<STUDENT>()` makes the instance of STUDENT that you assign to the pointer.

On the other hand c++ stl has a perfectly functional link-list class, as well.

Comment: The terms used in the standard are *block scoped* or *automatic* for the arrays (the stack is just an implementation detail) and pointers to variables that have reached their end of life and said *dangling*.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks, they are useful terms to look up for more detail.

Comment: how to avoid then this methods "dangerous" I wish that each node of different values ​​can be in my list

Comment: That entirely depends on how you intend to fill in the student details. Traditionally you create the records 1 at a time as you fill them in, and then it is clear that you need to use new to allocate them.

Comment: It's a technical nitpick but "*they become invalid and dangerous to use*" they are not dangerous to use... A pointer with invalid value cannot be practically used for anything other than resetting it's value to a valid one. Technically you can read it's value, or set to another invalid one, but I don't think it can be ever practical, at least not from top of my head. What op does is store a valid value in `i->students` but it does become invalid when the `insert_` ends, as you have said.

Comment: It's not possible, even using a vector or a table, it's the same thing. I am bored .
Ok, I'll send you another proposal to see if it works

Comment: The dangerous to use is that the address that the students points to is on the stack in the middle of the next called function. Go 2 function calls deep, and then change the content value student is pointing to, and you will change some stack value in the first function - it could be anything at that pointed to address - perhaps some other data variable, perhaps some function call management data. (That description is all very approximate, as functions use varying amounts of local data.)

Comment: What can you advise me, brieve, how can I do so that each node is on my list.
your old words are confusing my brain.
I try everything, if there is no possibility to do it, then tell me